# Why does accessing thread-local-storage (TLS) in library loaded by statically linked dlopen segfault?

Tags: gcc, c++, shared-library, glibc

I have an exe linked with gcc `-static` that uses `dlopen` to load a shared library. The library tries to access a variable in thread-local-storage (TLS). Running the application segfaults when we attempt to access the TLS variable. Removing the `-static` flag avoids the segfault.

Although this usage is unusual, is there actually anything incorrect about it?

The motivation behind this is to allow a statically linked exe to optionally load a plugin at run time when its dependencies are present, but function without them by default.
The need for TLS arises from its use in C++ exception handling (so I can't in general fix this by modifying how the shared libraries themselves are compiled).

```
==> main.c <==
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void* lib = dlopen("./libusetls.so", RTLD_NOW);
    typedef int func_t();
    func_t* function = dlsym(lib, "function");
    return function();
}

==> usetls.c <==
#include <stdio.h>

int function()
{
  static __thread int value = 0;
  return value;
}

==> makefile <==
 gcc -o main main.c -ldl -g -static

usetls.o: usetls.c makefile
 gcc -c -fPIC -o usetls.o usetls.c -g

libusetls.so: usetls.o makefile
 gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libusetls.so -o libusetls.so usetls.o -lc

clean:
 rm main usetls.o libusetls.so
```